# Wrong site root when testing web page from NetBeans

Tags: html, css, netbeans

This is a really basic one, I'm afraid, but it's driving me crazy.

I'm making a website using NetBeans. I have my `index.html` in the Site Root folder that NetBeans gives you, and when I test it with the Chrome plugin, it comes up successfully.

However, if I load CSS by absolute path, `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/layout.css" />`, it doesn't load properly, because NetBeans runs the local server within a folder with the same name as the project.

What I mean is, instead of NetBeans loading the website from `http://localhost:8383/index.html`, it instead loads it from `http://localhost:8383/ProjectName/index.html` and breaks all the paths.

The "site root" setting is set to `public_html`, which contains `index.html` directly.

This is the annoying kind of problem to which there is probably a really easy solution that I'm missing. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a relative URL to the CSS file?
Like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css" />
```

Comment: The problem with that is, I'd like to link to the same stylesheet from subpages within the site root folder, and I'd ideally like to copy-and-paste my <head> between all the index.html files. Is stuff like "../layout.css" my only option?

Answer (score 0):

*Note! This solution is working for one Neatbean project (site) at a time so it is not ideal but maybe good enough for many others. If someone have a solution that works for multiple projects I'm very interested in that solution as well.*

1. Set your server configuration to serve documents from your Netbean project folder, in XAMPP it looks like this.
   [image: Open configuration file in XAMPP]
   [image: Enter the project root location]
2. Set your Netbean project URL to "http://localhost/"
   [image: Project URL]
3. Now links starting with "/" will lead to your root as expected but if you switch project you will also need to do step 1 again.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Netbeans 12.1.

Right click on project - > Properties - > Run. Set Web Root to `/`

[image]

Benefits: paths relative to the root are properly working.

Disadvantages: impossible to work on several projects simultaneously.